# Infinite loop for async/await function that emits socket.io data to React app

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Haven't worked that much with `async/await` in my life but I've stumbled upon a problem where I need to use them in an infinite loop. The thing is, I'm trying to send system performances from my python app to my react via socket.io (fastapi version one) and I need to emit this data approximately every 10 seconds. If I wrap my socket emit code in a `while True` loop and add `await sleep(10)` at the end, no data is sent at all. If I remove the while loop, the data is sent only once and gets updated on each refresh. Any ideas how to solve this? My code:

```
@sio.on("connect", namespace='/ws')
async def print_message(sid, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        print("Connected " + str(sid))
        gpus = GPUtil.getGPUs()
        gpu_usage = 0
        for gpu in gpus:
            gpu_usage += gpu.load * 100
 
        gpu_usage = gpu_usage / len(gpus) if len(gpus) != 0 else 0
 
        await sio.emit("message", {'cpu': str(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0.5)) + '%',
                    'ram': str(psutil.virtual_memory()[2]) + '%', 'gpu': str(gpu_usage) + '%'}, namespace='/ws')
        await sleep(10) #asyncio sleep
```

Comment: I created a mini version of your function using the await sleep, and it worked fine. 

For your testing, you should determine where the problem is occurring. You should ask yourself if there are any unhandled exceptions happening in your loop? Try placing a try-catch in there and log any errors. Also, try writing to the console or a file throughout the "print_message" function and see where it might be hung up.

Comment: @GLJ wait, it did emit the data effectively every 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I'll paste the code I used for testing, and it printed to my console. Apologies for the bad formatting - don't think newlines are accepted in comments.

```import asyncio

async def print_message(sid, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        print("Connected " + str(sid))
        await asyncio.sleep(1) #asyncio sleep
```

```async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(print_message(1))
```

```asyncio.run(main())```